# NRules - Organizing Rules

Tags: nrules

When organizing rules for NRules, is it necessary to only have 1 When/Then group in a file?

I have one rule that looks at 3 conditions (fact matches), is flagA = false, inputA = one of a list of values, and inputB = a single value. When all true, set flagA to true. I got that one working,then wanted to add the second rule.

The second rule is when flagA is false and flagB is true then set flagA to true.

Do these two rules need to be in separate .cs files or can they be together in one.

I looked at the ".Or" option, but I am not good enough with fluent to figure out what it is doing.

Thanks for your help,
Toom

Answer (score 0):

In NRules an instance of a class that inherits from `NRules.Fluent.Dsl.Rule` is one rule. You can put multiple rule classes in one .cs file or different files, it does not matter - each class is still a separate rule.

In that rule class, you normally would specify `When` and `Then` sections only once. If you specify them multiple times, all conditions would still be combined into a single set using `and` group. Actions would also be merged into a single set.

So:

```cs
public class Rule1: Rule
{
    public override void Define()
    {
        When()
            .Match<A>();
        Then()
            .Do(_ => X());

        When()
            .Match<B>();
        Then()
            .Do(_ => Y());
    }
}
```

is exactly the same as

```cs
public class Rule1: Rule
{
    public override void Define()
    {
        When()
            .Match<A>()
            .Match<B>();
        Then()
            .Do(_ => X())
            .Do(_ => Y());
    }
}
```

In other words, both examples above create just a single rule that matches both `A` and `B`, and if both those facts match, then both `X` and `Y` methods are executed.

If you want that to be two independent rules, then put those different When/Then sections into different rule classes.

```cs
public class Rule1: Rule
{
    public override void Define()
    {
        When()
            .Match<A>();
        Then()
            .Do(_ => X());
    }
}

public class Rule2: Rule
{
    public override void Define()
    {
        When()
            .Match<B>();
        Then()
            .Do(_ => Y());
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
If you wanted to connect conditions `A` and `B` with an `OR`, you could do it like below. Here the rule will fire if `((A OR B) AND C)`:

```cs
public class Rule1: Rule
{
    public override void Define()
    {
        When()
            .Or(x => x
                .Match<A>()
                .Match<B>())
            .Match<C>();
        Then()
            .Do(_ => Z());
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that clears up that part for me. Now, the reason I was trying 2 rules is that I had 2 conditions that would trigger a true condition. The ".Or" clause confused me.

Comment: Great, so does this give you what you need?

Comment: There is the .OR In a standard if statement this case would be something like:

Comment: Are you asking how to write an Or condition?

Comment: I updated the answer including the explanation of how to use the Or group

Comment: OK, thanks for the OR update. I'm going to go try it now in my real system.